Why extent of std::span created from a static array considered to have a dynamic_extent?
Why is the following static array considered to have a dynamic extent?
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
     
int main()
{
    char static_array[]={1,2,3};
    std::span<char> sp{static_array};
    if (std::dynamic_extent == sp.extent)
        std::cout << "Why dynamic?" << std::endl;
}

This prints: "Why dynamic?" so this is clearly not how it is supposed to be used. What am I missing?

There's no partial class template argument deduction. Since you specified some template parameters (<...>), the extent template parameter is going to use its default value (that being std::dynamic_extent) instead of being deduced. If you want it to be deduced, you have to drop <...>.

The std::span extent is dynamic by default even though the owning array's extent is not.
If you want it to have a static extent, specify it upon construction:
std::span<char, std::size(static_array)> sp{static_array};
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Or just don't specify any template parameters to let them be deduced:
std::span sp{static_array};

In the latter case, the below deduction guide will make the extent static:
template< class T, std::size_t N >
span( T (&)[N] ) -> span<T, N>;

